# Beacon status not authorized by one app, but seen as unregistered by another app

Tags: android, eddystone, google-beacon-platform, google-developers-console, proximityapi

I'm learning how to build an application that can detect eddystone beacons near by, by following the example of Google's Beacon Service Demo app, that can be found here https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples/android .

In my application I have partly the same functionality regarding the discovery and management of beacon devices.

I'm using two eddystone beacon devices to test the applications, both are configured with a unique beacon ID.

Using Google's Beacon Service Demo App, I could detect both of these beacons and their status was **UNREGISTERED**. I registered one of them and now it's in an **ACTIVE** status.

Whith my app, I can detect them as well, but their status appears to be **UNAUTHORISED**.

I believe I have created correctly my project at Google Developer Console and have enabled successfully the Proximity API with an API key associated with both of these apps, and have generated an OAuth 2.0 client ID for each.

Why could it be that the app I'm developing doesn't have access to the same beacons as the sample Google app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had used an incorrect sha key to generate the OAuth 2.0 client ID for my application.